# How does Enterprise Ethereum manage authentication?

Tags: poa, enterprise

I`m sorry for my bad english.

I am struggling between enterprise ethereum and hyperledger fabric.

1. I saw in the docs that Hyperledger fabric manages parts of certification and accreditation. How is the enterprise ehtereum managed?

I only know that enterprise ehtereum use POA consensus. If you know a site that you can refer to, please recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ethereum there is no centralized certificate authority server like that of hyperledger fabric. Fabric is a private permissioned blockchain and all the participants need to be known. Hence the CA issues the identity.

Ethereum is a public network. Ethereum accounts can be created by anyone. Account creation in ethereum is basically generating a BIP39 mnemonic which can be used to generate number of cryptographic key pairs, a private and public key. The private key controls the account and an address derived from the public key is used to identify the account.

Comment: So, What you're saying is that private ethereum also has no part about CA?

Comment: This is not true as he is asking about Enterprise Ethereum which are focuses on Private networks which are ultimately bridged to the Publicj Chain Mainnet and has a rapidly evolving spec

Comment: Private networks are in principle similar to the public networks but are within the confines of an organizational network. In such a network you can implement a contract or an off chain solution that maps addresses to real identities. But the account creation remains the same.